# Create columns based on the values in another data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame called df that contains 2 columns; user and artist.

```
head(df, 5)
                                  user               artist
1 3bd73256-3905-4f3a-97e2-8b341527f805      betty blowtorch
2 f2fb0ff0-5679-42ec-a55c-15109ce6e320            die Ärzte
3 b3ae82c2-e60b-4551-a76d-6620f1b456aa    melissa etheridge
4 3d6bbeb7-f90e-4d10-b440-e153c0d10b53            elvenking
5 bbd2ffd7-17f4-4506-8572-c1ea58c3f9a8 juliette & the licks
```

I want to create another data frame that gives each entry in the artist column a row that is then represented by a 0 or 1 based on if the user ID has an entry for that artist. Here is an example of the results I am trying to get:

```
user                                             betty blowtorch   die Ärzte    melissa etheridge   elvenking   juliette & the licks
        1 3bd73256-3905-4f3a-97e2-8b341527f805             1              0           0                   0            0
        2 3bd73256-3905-4f3a-97e2-8b341527f805             0              1           0                   0            0
        3 f2fb0ff0-5679-42ec-a55c-15109ce6e320             0              1           0                   0            0
        4 b3ae82c2-e60b-4551-a76d-6620f1b456aa             0              0           1                   0            0
        5 3d6bbeb7-f90e-4d10-b440-e153c0d10b53             0              0           0                   1            0
        6 bbd2ffd7-17f4-4506-8572-c1ea58c3f9a8             0              0           0                   0            1
        7 bbd2ffd7-17f4-4506-8572-c1ea58c3f9a8             0              0           0                   1            0
```

If the user ID appears in df multiple times, then I need a new row for that user, so each row will only have one 1 value (see above example).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr`'s function `pivot_wider` here with `values_fn` and `values_fill`, which will return a data frame (which I assume you want):

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = artist, 
                   values_from = artist, 
                   values_fn = list(artist = length),
                   values_fill = list(artist = 0))
```

Output:

```
user                      `betty blowtorch` `die Ärzte` `melissa etheridge` elvenking `juliette & the licks`
  <chr>                                 <int>       <int>               <int>     <int>                  <int>
1 3bd73256-3905-4f3a-97e2-…                 1           0                   0         0                      0
2 f2fb0ff0-5679-42ec-a55c-…                 0           1                   0         0                      0
3 b3ae82c2-e60b-4551-a76d-…                 0           0                   1         0                      0
4 3d6bbeb7-f90e-4d10-b440-…                 0           0                   0         1                      0
5 bbd2ffd7-17f4-4506-8572-…                 0           0                   0         0                      1
```

Or in base R, a simple table may work, but will return a table structure:

```
table(df$user, df$artist)

 # or for data frame
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$user, df$artist))
```

Output:

```
                                      betty blowtorch die Ärzte elvenking juliette & the licks melissa etheridge
  3bd73256-3905-4f3a-97e2-8b341527f805               1         0         0                    0                 0
  3d6bbeb7-f90e-4d10-b440-e153c0d10b53               0         0         1                    0                 0
  b3ae82c2-e60b-4551-a76d-6620f1b456aa               0         0         0                    0                 1
  bbd2ffd7-17f4-4506-8572-c1ea58c3f9a8               0         0         0                    1                 0
  f2fb0ff0-5679-42ec-a55c-15109ce6e320               0         1         0                    0                 0
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "user               artist
1 3bd73256-3905-4f3a-97e2-8b341527f805      'betty blowtorch'
2 f2fb0ff0-5679-42ec-a55c-15109ce6e320            'die Ärzte'
3 b3ae82c2-e60b-4551-a76d-6620f1b456aa    'melissa etheridge'
4 3d6bbeb7-f90e-4d10-b440-e153c0d10b53            elvenking
5 bbd2ffd7-17f4-4506-8572-c1ea58c3f9a8 'juliette & the licks'", h = TRUE)
```